# Plotting points around a circle non-uniformly

Tags: math, plot, trigonometry

I would like to create this effect in code - where a series of points are plotted around a circle, however I would like to bunch the points closer together at the left & right hand sides of the circle and space them out (evenly) further apart at the top and bottom.

I feel this should be possible using standard sin/cos/tan functions but I can't figure it out.

[image: Desired outcome]

Here's my pseudo code so far to create a circle but with uniformly spread points:

```
var angleIncrement = (2 * Math.PI) / numPoints;
    
for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
  var angle = i * angleIncrement;
  var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle);

  points.push(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Don't increase your `angle` by a uniform amount? Come up with a rule for how much to increment the angle by, given the angle you're at now, and then use that instead. (also, this looks like JS, so if it is: time to stop using `var`, it was replaced by the pair of `let` and `const` _quite_ a long time ago now. Unless you're stuck in something like Adobe's Scripting for Photoshop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try subtracting from the angle half the sine of twice the same angle. This should transform the linear function of the point index `i` into an "upward sine wave" that crosses the linear function at n π with derivative `0` and at (n + ½) π with derivative `2`. Something like (untested!):

```js
    var angleIncrement = (2 * Math.PI) / numPoints;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
      var linearAngle = i * angleIncrement;
      var angle = linearAngle - 0.5 * Math.sin(linearAngle * 2);
      var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
      var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle);

      points.push(x, y);
    }
```

For less oscillation, replace that `0.5` by a smaller factor.